# Convert List to String when invoke api methods throw resteasy

Tags: java, resteasy

I have interface which map vk.com api for get friends.

```
@Path("/friends.get")
public interface VkFriendsRequester {

    @GET
    VkFriendsResponse getFriends(
            @QueryParam("user_id") Long userId,
            @QueryParam("order") String order,
            @QueryParam("list_id") Long listId,
            @QueryParam("count") Integer count,
            @QueryParam("offset") Integer offset,
            @QueryParam("fields") Collection<String> fields,
            @QueryParam("name_case") String nameCase,
            @QueryParam("access_token") String accessToken,
            @QueryParam("v") String version,
            @QueryParam("lang") String language
    );
}
```

Here I have `@QueryParam("fields") Collection<String> fields` parameter. By default when I pass array here RestEasy convert it like `fields=fields1&fields=fields2&fields=fields3...`, but vk.com api needs something like this: `fields=fields1,fields2,fields3...`.

I found that I need to create provider which implements StringConverter interface.
Here it's code

```
@Provider
public class StringCollectionConverter implements StringConverter<Collection<String>> {

    @Override
    public Collection<String> fromString(String string) {
        if (string == null) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        return Arrays.asList(string.split(","));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(Collection<String> values) {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for (String value : values) {
            if (first) {
                first = false;
            } else {
                sb.append(",");
            }
            sb.append(value);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

But restesy doesn't invokes this methods.
I tried to register this provider in web.xml but this didn't help anyway.

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
        <param-value>
            net.wideup.common.rest.DefaultExceptionHandler,
            net.wideup.common.rest.StringCollectionConverter
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on the following article: https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html/StringConverter.html

Search for `DateFormatter`. This example is exactly what you need. 
The author created converter and a special custom annotation that he uses to mark the parameter that should be converted. He converts string to date, you can convert it to `List<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested and debugged your code (exactly as you posted it), and it works perfectly. Please do note that

1. it is not necessary to add the Converter to your web.xml, it is automatically detected (at least in my Java EE environment).
2. if 1. is correct in your case, then check that you do not have another `StringConverter` in your jars, that is responsible for the type `Collection` (no matter what kind of collection e.g `Collection<Long>`), as you might have only ONE StringConverter for the a raw type (as I noticed).
3. if nothing helps, consider upgrading your version. I use resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2 (which SHOULD be deployed in your environment, *CHECK THAT*)